# Swift file to contain multiple TableView code for one Imageview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have multiple tableviews in my app that when the user clicks a cell, a specific image on one view controller. Because I have many table views, I wanted to have the code for multiple in one file. The code I have now opens the first "cardiac" tableview and can click on a cell to view the picture, but for the others, the app crashes; even with the code compiling. I can't figure out why, and am sure it's something simple. My code is below:

```
    import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

///You are using this class a UIViewCOntroller in storyBoard bbut hadnt provided **tablelist: UIViewController**
///This is Necessary in case when you are going to assign it to a UIVIewController
class adultprotocols: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.red]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes



        ///You need to Sert datasource and Delegate as its not a TableViewController its just a Normal TableView
        self.cardiacTableView.dataSource = self
        self.cardiacTableView.delegate = self




        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black


        //---------ADS-------------------------------------------
        // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    }


    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
            ])


        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }




    //--------------------------LIST Specs-------------------------------------------------------//

    let cardiac = ["one", "twoasdg", "Cowasdasd", "Mulvadasdal"]
    let respiratory = ["one", "AsdaSD", "asdasdadad"]
    let trauma = ["one", "two", "three"]
    let ams = ["one","two"]

    ///You did not connected a outlet of tableView
    ///as its not a tableViewController just a TableView so it should be Connected
    @IBOutlet weak var animalTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var cardiacTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var respiratoryTableView: UITableView!


    ///Set elements in cell
    func tableView(  _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "adultcardiaclist"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = cardiac[indexPath.row]
        // FONT STYLE
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.cardiacTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        return cell
    }
    func resptableView(  _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "adultrespiratorylist"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = respiratory[indexPath.row]
        // FONT STYLE
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.respiratoryTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        return cell
    }
    func traumatableView(  _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "adulttraumalist"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = cardiac[indexPath.row]
        // FONT STYLE
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.cardiacTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        return cell
    }
    func amstableView(  _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "adultamslist"/*Identifier*/, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = cardiac[indexPath.row]
        // FONT STYLE
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.cardiacTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return cardiac.count
    }
    func resptableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return respiratory.count
    }
    func traumatableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return trauma.count
    }
    func amstableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return ams.count
    }


    //--------------------------Cardiac List--------------------
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        ///Right way here
        ///You can easily manage using this
        let Vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageViewController") as! imageViewController

        ///Here you have written four Animal names in Array
        ///So There is going to four case 0,1,2,3 and a default case
        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 0:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image1")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;
        case 1:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image2")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;
        case 2:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image3")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;
        case 3:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image1")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
            break;
        default:
            Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image2")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func resptableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        ///Right way here
        ///You can easily manage using this
        let Bv = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageViewController") as! imageViewController

        ///Here you have written four Animal names in Array
        ///So There is going to four case 0,1,2,3 and a default case
        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 0:
            Bv.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image1")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Bv, animated: true)
            break;
        case 1:
            Bv.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image2")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Bv, animated: true)
            break;
        case 2:
            Bv.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image3")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Bv, animated: true)
            break;
        case 3:
            Bv.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image1")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Bv, animated: true)
            break;
        default:
            Bv.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "image2")!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Bv, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Am i using the "func tableview" "func resptableview" incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague. What line is crashing, and with what error message?

My guess is that you are crashing due to using the force unwrap (`!`) operator. I call that the "crash if nil" operator, because that's what it does.

You should make the destination `imageViewController`'s `passedImage` property an `Optional`, and get rid of the force-unwrap. Then write your imageViewController so it handles the case where the image view is nil.

As a beginner, you should avoid the force-unwrap operator completely. The only time I would suggest using it is when Xcode sets up an `IBOutlet` as a force-unwrapped optional, since you want to know right away if you have a broken outlet link, and crashing when it's not lets you know about the problem early.

Also avoid `as!` force casting. That's another case where you crash if it fails. Get used to using `guard` statements or `if let` optional binding instead.

Comment: I guess im wondering why my code works for one tableview and not the other. Also, why can't i just edit one of the 'func tableview' code to work for another tableview. My error is: "NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier adultcardiaclist - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:"

Comment: You need to use different unique identifiers for each different type of cell, and will need to write your `cellForRow(at:)` method to use the table view parameter to figure out which type of cell to create.